# LinQ Query Builder to .cs file in C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, code-generation

As you know we use LinQ Technology to SQL Classes for send and get results to SQL. If I have a table called User in SQL, I write queries in C# like

```
List<User> allUsers = (from s in dataContext.Users select s).ToList();
```

or

```
// Update Query

User u = (from s in dataContext.Users where s.Id.Equals(1) select s).First();

u.Name = "serkan";

dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

We called this CRUD services (Create-Update-Delete).

My Question is, if I have a table required CRUD more than 40+, I need to write same codes. It will take too much times to write. Is there any Tool (ex Generator) to get table names from given SQL Con, and write base methods (CRUD) to .cs file? If not, I gonna write a tool in C#, but firstly I want to know. Searched at google a bit, but cant find enough info.

**EDIT: While waiting for answers, I started to type a tool. It will be like this, but I will be very happy, If a tool already written in c# :)**

```
private List<string> myClasses = new List<string>();
        private const string myDataContextName = "SurfTurkeyDataContext";

        private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                sb.AppendLine("using System;");
                sb.AppendLine("using System.Collections.Generic;");
                sb.AppendLine("using System.Linq;");
                sb.AppendLine("using System.Text;");
                sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
                sb.AppendLine("namespace LinqToCsGenerator");
                sb.AppendLine("{");
                sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);

                //Class Initilize
                sb.AppendLine("public class Users");
                sb.AppendLine("{");

                foreach (string item in myClasses)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);

                    // Select All Method
                    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("public List<{0}> GetAll{0}()", item));
                    sb.AppendLine("{");
                    sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} dc = new {0}();", myDataContextName));
                    sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("List<{0}> all{0} = (from s in dc.{0} select s).ToList();", item));
                    sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("return all{0};", item));
                    sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.AppendLine("}");
                    sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);

                    // Insert Method
                    // Delete Method
                    //.
                    //.
                    //.
                    //.
                }

                sb.AppendLine("}");
                sb.AppendLine("}");

                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\deneme.cs", sb.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myClasses.Add("Users");
            myClasses.Add("Products");
        }
```

Comment: goood, go on, build one, and let me know as well :)

Comment: @Zein Shaikh as I said, If there isnt any tool, I need to write it, and yes I will let you know when I found a tool, or wrote a tool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PLINQO and Codesmith Combo ->
http://community.codesmithtools.com/CodeSmith_Community/b/pwelter/archive/2007/08/08/plinqo.aspx

Comment: This is very close to what Im looking for. Checking more, will return feedback to you. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, Code Smith's Tool is really good, its a bit complicated, but if you solve how to use it, its easy. Thanks for your answer. This tool can be accepted as a solution.

Comment: Yeah, I agree its a bit complicated but once you get it right then its a breeze.  I used this tool long time ago when LINQ was not yet around.  So I used it in combination with .netTiers

Answer (score 1):

Look at Text Template Transformation Kit for Visual Studio - T4.